# Google web toolkit error running mvn package

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I've a project written using gwt and I've the following error when running "mvn package":

```
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:1.0-rc-8:compile (default) @ Ifrs9-Web ---
[INFO] Compiling module iason.ifrs9.web.client.Ifrs9EntryPoint
[INFO]    Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.smartgwt.client.bean.types.EnumValueType'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/Users/andrea/.m2/repository/com/smartgwt/smartgwt/4.0/smartgwt-4.0.jar!/com/smartgwt/client/bean/types/EnumValueType.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 26: Name clash: The method registerValueType(Class<T>) of type EnumValueType<ValueType> has the same erasure as registerValueType(Class<T>) of type OtherValueType<ValueType> but does not hide it
[INFO]    Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.smartgwt.client.bean.types.JsoValueType'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/Users/andrea/.m2/repository/com/smartgwt/smartgwt/4.0/smartgwt-4.0.jar!/com/smartgwt/client/bean/types/JsoValueType.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 31: Name clash: The method registerValueType(Class<T>) of type JsoValueType<ValueType> has the same erasure as registerValueType(Class<T>) of type OtherValueType<ValueType> but does not hide it
[INFO]    Finding entry point classes
[INFO]       [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:15 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-24T11:47:23+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/212M
```

Could you please help me to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

This is already answered in the SmartGWT forum: 
https://forums.smartclient.com/forum/smart-gwt-technical-q-a/30377-cannot-compile-smartgwt-4-0-with-gwt-2-6-and-jdk-1-7

Upgrade to a most recent version. Builds available here: 
https://www.smartclient.com/builds/index.jsp

Comment: Where I can find a maven repository to download the dependency?

Comment: No idea, ask in the samrtgwt forum. You can also download and configure maven to use that local lib.